# Ubuntu 22.04 UI issues: In-app file selector/save prompt, saving files and new window location issues

Tags: nautilus, snap, gui, window, 22.04

To start off: none of these were issues on 21.10 or prior.

Regardless of what app (for example Firefox (while downloading) or Signal (while uploading)) , the file-selector/save prompt (depending on what I'm doing) will resize a bit larger every time it opens, till it reaches max-dimensions, alongside this I can't seem to save any files unless I click on the filename text field and make a change, if I don't it'll just close the prompt as if it has saved it (but it hasn't).

Another issue is that all new windows for any apps (for example Terminal or Text Editor) won't remember their last position and open from the top-left of the screen.

My question is; Am I missing some system files? My installation was fresh and smooth, no errors, prior to which I was using 21.10 which had no issues.

My laptop is an HP Elitebook 840 G3.

EDIT:

```
$ wmctrl -m
Name: GNOME Shell
Class: N/A
PID: N/A
Window manager's "showing the desktop" mode: OFF
```

Comment: These settings are handled by Window Managers. Could you update the description with result of this command" `wmctrl -m`

Comment: @JijoJoseph alrighty, done.

Comment: Oh yes, I'm using budgie desktop that's why didn't think you're using GNOME. You must install gnome-tweaks and open the app. Under windows section, there's a setting to keep the new windows centered. As far as I know, that's the solution for GNOME. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yea I already have that option but it's not what I was looking for, windows should remember their last position as previous versions did, thanks anyway!

Comment: Same issue. Super annoying. The nautilus window gets so big it's off the screen and unusable. :P

Comment: @Trees4theForest Thanks for commenting! Hopefully more people report the issue so it gets resolved quickly.

Comment: I confirm the presence of this problem for Chromium-based browsers, as well as Firefox. The dialog box for opening a file or saving a file remembers the set size, but each time it is opened, it increases its size until it takes up the whole screen. This is very unpleasant dialog box behavior. In Gnome applications such as Gedit - this is not observed, everything works fine. I thought it might be related to snap packages, so I installed the Brave version according to the instructions on their site. It's not the snap version. So, this erroneous open dialog box behavior is also present in Brave.

Comment: The saving files issue seems to have be fixed in the latest update.

Comment: @Hannah Is this update available on Ubuntu 22.04? I couldn't find any new updates as of yet through a `sudo apt update`.

Answer (score 1):

filed upstream

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/4136
The bug is seven months old so it's not getting much love, although in the couple of weeks it has become an active bug report.

you can follow progress at the link. It doesn't happen if the snap is native wayland.
It seems to be related to gtk4, although Ubuntu tried to avoid gtk4 due to concerns that it would have bugs. Got that right.

The bug report is very recently active but not showing signs of much progress yet.

Answer (score 1):

The resizing bug is [fixed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk4/+bug/1971112/comments/13) in the Ubuntu `libgtk-4-1` package, version `4.6.5+ds-1ubuntu1`. As of July 2022, this version is not in the default main repositories yet, but it is available in the `proposed` repositories.

You can check your current version of GTK with the following command:

```
apt-cache policy libgtk-4-1
```

By the following [method from the Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed), you can enable the `proposed` repository and install the proposed GTK packages while keeping all other packages from the main repositories:

Add the proposed repository to sources:

```
# As root:

cat <<EOF > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-$(lsb_release -cs)-proposed.list
# Enable Ubuntu proposed archive
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ $(lsb_release -cs)-proposed restricted main multiverse universe
EOF
```

Prevent packages from the proposed repository from being installed by default:

```
# As root:

cat <<EOF > /etc/apt/preferences.d/proposed-updates
# Configure apt to allow selective installs of packages from proposed
Package: *
Pin: release a=$(lsb_release -cs)-proposed
Pin-Priority: 400
EOF
```

Install the latest GTK packages from the proposed repository:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libgtk-4-1/$(lsb_release -cs)-proposed
```

Comment: Awesome, just confirmed this. I hope it makes it into the main repo soon. Thanks.