# 22.04 file chooser automatically resizing in snap apps

Tags: snap, gtk4

The open and save file dialog windows in Firefox or Brave enlarge themselves in 1 second intervals until they take up the entire screen and do not respond correctly to input, automatically reopening. It is possible to close the misbehaving app from the dock. Resetting org.gtk.gtk4.Settings.FileChooser window-size to (-1, -1) only loops back to a new file chooser dialog being the correct size for the first second. Deb/apt pacakged apps like Evince don't have this issue.

Comment: I confirm this buggy behavior.

Comment: You probably need to file a bug report. I doubt anyone here can fix this. And probably against those 2 browsers (as both are 3rd party) in combination with qt4.

Comment: Good call on qt, the VLC snap doesn't suffer from this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 22.04 UI issues: In-app file selector/save prompt, saving files and new window location issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405901/ubuntu-22-04-ui-issues-in-app-file-selector-save-prompt-saving-files-and-new-w)